# Why is the output only the last value? Oracle loop cursor

Tags: oracle, loops, cursor

I'm trying to output a list of the courses a professor teaches, by receiving the prof's id by parameter to my function, and showing all courses, each separated by a comma. For example, if a Professor teaches Humanities, Science and Math, I want the output to be: 'Humanities, Science, Math'. However, I'm getting just 'Math,'. It only shows the last field that it found that matched with the prof's id.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION listar_cursos(prof NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR
IS
    CURSOR C1 IS
        SELECT subject.name AS name FROM subject
               INNER JOIN course_semester 
               ON subject.id = course_semester.id_subject
        WHERE  course_semester.id_profesor = prof
        ORDER BY subject.name;

    test VARCHAR(500);
BEGIN
    FOR item IN C1
    LOOP
        test:= item.name ||',';
    END LOOP;

    RETURN test;
END;
/
```

I am aware that listagg exists, however I do not wish to use it.

Comment: Well, for one thing it seems you want the list ordered alphabetically (you seem to want to do that in the CURSOR). **Math** is not the last one alphabetically, **Science** is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loop, you re-assign to the `test` variable, instead of appending to it. This is why, at the end of the loop, it will just hold the last value of `item.name`.

The assignment should instead be something like

```
test := test || ',' || item.name
```

Note also that this will leave a comma at the beginning of the string. Instead of returning `test`, you may want to return `ltrim(test, ',')`.

Note that you don't need to declare a cursor explicitly. The code is easier to read (in my opinion) with an implicit cursor, as shown below. I create sample tables and data to test the function, then I show the function code and how it's used.

```
create table subject as
  select 1 id, 'Humanities' name from dual union all
  select 2   , 'Science'         from dual union all
  select 3   , 'Math'            from dual
;

create table course_semester as
  select 1 id_subject, 201801 semester, 1002 as id_profesor from dual union all
  select 2           , 201702         , 1002 as id_profesor from dual union all
  select 3           , 201801         , 1002 as id_profesor from dual
;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION listar_cursos(prof NUMBER)  RETURN VARCHAR IS
 test VARCHAR(500);
BEGIN
FOR item IN 
(
  SELECT subject.name AS name FROM subject
      INNER JOIN course_semester 
  ON subject.id = course_semester.id_subject
  WHERE course_semester.id_profesor = prof
  ORDER BY subject.name
)
LOOP
  test:= test || ',' || item.name;
END LOOP;
RETURN ltrim(test, ',');
END;
/

select listar_cursos(1002) from dual;

LISTAR_CURSOS(1002)
-----------------------
Humanities,Math,Science
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You were very helpful :)